# Postgreqsl Query Error

Tags: postgresql

I'm running the following query and it's saying that it is not valid:

```
redmine=# ALTER TABLE changesets ALTER COLUMN committer TYPE character varying(100);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TYPE" at character 47
```

Does anyone have any idea on the solution to this issue?

Comment: Is this an exact copy of your input? The Postgres manual even lists this as an example (with different names of course) so the syntax should be correct. What version are you using? Does it happen when you say `varchar(100)` instead of `character varying(100)`?

Comment: Im using ph 7.4, and yes it still errors without character

Comment: 7.4 is not supported anymore, you should consider upgrading to a newer version: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Release_Support_Policy

Comment: @Frank - I've done that now, was much easier and also fixed another issue I was having :)

Comment: Release policy has been moved to official site: http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres 7.4 [does not support retyping columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/sql-altertable.html). You have to create a new column, copy over any data, drop the old column and rename the new to have the old name.

If there is no data to copy, you can of course simply drop the old column and create the new column with the new type.

Comment: If you go far enough back, pgsql didn't support dropping columns.